# Spring Boot из Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно добавить в существующий Spring MVC maven проект, чтоб получить Spring Boot проект? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что вы хотите получить в итоге? Что из Spring Boot вам необходимо/не хватает?

Скорее всего понадобится добавить:

- класс c методом `main()` и разными аннотациями
- плагин для сборки
- отнаследоваться от их родительского артефакта
- добавить стартеры по вкусу

И, естественно, все это и даже много-много больше есть в их документации: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html

Comment: Странная штука...Есть мой проэкт, который работает, просто через томкэт. Добавляю все вышеперечисленное вами и...Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addCollectionConverters(Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConverterRegistry;)V from class org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedConversionServiceю Хочу получить проэк для зпуска без делоя в Томкэт(пока в образовательных целях).

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, насколько понимаю.

Comment: Это да, а помочь в нем сможете? Я так изначально по документации сделал, но запустить не могу

Comment: Самое главное, чем я могу вам помочь, это привить идею, что сначала нужно гуглить и также нужно читать документацию. Вот, я только что по вашей ошибке уже нашел ответ на StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Теперь такой Exception:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed